# Rails Cookie Detection Script Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies

I wanted to make sure that users have cookies enabled for my site, so I used [this guide](http://clearcove.ca/2009/09/rails-cookie-detection/).

However, when I run my server, I gut this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
map.cookies_test “cookie_test”, :controller...
```

Here's my application_controller.rb :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    include CookieDetection
    include SessionsHelper
end
```

and my routes.rb :

```
Basketball::Application.routes.draw do

  map.cookies_test “cookie_test”, :controller => “application”, :action => “cookie_test”

  resources :games 

  resources :teams

  get "teams/new"
  get "games/new"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete  

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

### Update

I have changed my quotes from "smart" quotes to plain quotes (as per Edward), but I am now getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `map' for#
<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007ff9ca996800> (NameError)
```

### Update

I have changed Map to Match (as per Edward) and am now getting the error:

```
`match': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your routes file, it look like you've got "smart" quotes “” ,rather than plain "

I expect you've cut and pasted them by mistake.

Edit

---

Change map to match - map is rails 2